# Is it safe to attach battery when the laptop is plugged in and being used?

Tags: laptop, battery

Let say initially I removed my laptop battery because it's already fully charged. Then I plug in my laptop to the wall socket, and then use my laptop. After that, I need to go somewhere, but I don't want to shut down my laptop, attach the battery, and then power it on again. So I attach my battery without shutting down the laptop. Is this safe? Or will it damage either the laptop or the battery or both?

Answer (score 2):

Removing and inserting the battery is [completely safe](http://batterycare.net/en/guide.html) ([for the computer](https://superuser.com/questions/12838/should-laptops-remain-plugged-in-when-their-battery-is-100-charged)) [when your computer is plugged in](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/remove-laptop-battery-increase-life-geeks-weigh/).  You may want to watch your fingers though.

If you lose power while you are doing something critical like an update or installing something, that may cause problems however as the computer may not be able to save it's state properly for the next time it powers up and things may get wonky.

[Consequences of turning off computer during Windows Vista update (“Do not turn off your computer”)?](https://superuser.com/questions/648991/what-happen-when-we-shutdown-system-during-os-update-process)

Comment: Do you have any additional information on why this is the case?